# Secure.class not found

Tags: security, playframework

I am following the documentation for configuring [the Secure module](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.5/secure), but I'm getting the below error

```
Compilation error

HTTP Verb (GET, POST, ...), include (->) or comment (#) expected 
c:\play-2.2.2-RC2\EstimationTool\conf\routes at line 17.

GET         /assets/*file        controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)

# Import Secure routes

 *       /                                       module:secure
```

I have the impression the documentation I am referring too is old..

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: "I have the impression the documentation I am referring too is old." Indeed, 1.2.5 is old.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, your documentation is about an old version (1.2.5 in url vs 2.2.2 for your play version)

You can find modules for play 2.2.2 at http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Modules